# Owl Carousel v2.2.0 is not showing number of items based on screensize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have a simple Carousel which is using old version `Owl Carousel v2.2.0` for some reason it work only for large screen and take =default value of large screen only. and it doesn't act responsively on another screen.

Carousel should show 3 items on desktop, 2 items on Table and 1 item on mobile.

Carousel work but shows 3 items for all screens size https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/abjZLbQ

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#slider-carousel").owlCarousel({
    rtl: true,
    //autoPlay: 5000, Set AutoPlay to 5 seconds
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 3],
    itemsTablet: [768, 2],
    itemsTabletSmall: false,
    //itemsMobile: [479, 1],
    itemsMobile: false, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
    pagination: false,
    dots: false,
    //video:true,
    // autoplayHoverPause: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-right'></i>",
      "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-left'></i>"
      //  "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-left'></i>",
      // "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-right'></i>"
    ],
    afterInit: function (elem) {
      var that = this;
      that.owlControls.prependTo(elem);
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme ">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3" alt="" />
        </div>
           <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=4" alt="" />
        </div>
           <div class="item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=5" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am not sure what is causing this behavior. Since this is old website which I can't change this to latest carousel version. For some reason it seems broken.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle i found the solution, right way of adding responsive feature to this is with below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#slider-carousel").owlCarousel({
    //rtl: true,
    //autoPlay: 5000, Set AutoPlay to 5 seconds
 items: 3,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                479: {
                    items: 1
                },
                768: {
                    items: 3
                },
                980: {
                    items: 3
                },
                1199: {
                    items: 3
                }
            },
    pagination: false,
    dots: false,
    //video:true,
    // autoplayHoverPause: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-right'></i>",
      "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-left'></i>"
      //  "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-left'></i>",
      // "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-right'></i>"
    ],
    afterInit: function (elem) {
      var that = this;
      that.owlControls.prependTo(elem);
    }
  });
});
```

After adding it it worked fine, the way mentioned in question is for older version owl Carousel  v1.xx